# Capturing Google Maps Marker drag event

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-markers

My application uses markers in Google Maps, each marker represents several types (eg home, person, car).

I would like that when I drag a marker to another marker I could get where I finished my drag? For example when I drag the corresponding marker has a "person" to the corresponding marker has a "home".

When I drag the marker "person" the event "mouseover" of the "house marker" is not triggered. Is it possible to intercept this event during evt drag the marker "person" or should I use a different method?

Answer (score 0):

> When I drag the marker "person" the event "mouseover" of the "house marker" is not triggered

It should/does trigger.